# React hooks - change state inside scroll event not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I try to change `myState` inside scroll `handle` function like

```
const [myState, setMyState] = useState(false);
const refA = useRef(null)
const handle = (e) => {
    if (!myState) {
        console.log('Set', myState)
        setMyState(true);
    }else {
        console.log('no set')
    }
}
useEffect(() => {
    if (props.run) {
        const ref= refA.current
        ref.addEventListener("scroll", handle, { passive: true });
    }
}, [props.run]); 

useEffect(() => {
    const ref= refA.current
        return () => {
            ref.removeEventListener("scroll", handle, { passive: true });
        }
}, [])

return (
    <div ref={refA}>
        <p>long</p><br/>
        <p>long</p><br/>
        <p>long</p><br/>
        <p>long</p><br/>
        <p>long</p><br/>
        <p>long</p><br/>
        <p>long</p><br/>
        <p>long</p><br/>
        <p>long</p><br/>
        <p>long</p><br/>
        <p>long</p><br/>
        <p>long</p><br/>
    </div>
);
```

But when i scroll my div, log is always show `Set`? `myState` can't change data? how to fix that thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `myState` in the `useEffect`. And add `removeEventListener` in `return` of this `useEffect`, don't need create other `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (props.run) {
    const ref = refA.current;
    ref.addEventListener("scroll", handle, { passive: true });
    return () => {
      ref.removeEventListener("scroll", handle, { passive: true });
    };
  }
}, [props.run, myState]);
```

Add `myState` in the dependencies will call `useEffect` when this state change. And the variable in the `handle` will be updated with new state.

You should return `removeEventListener` after call `addEventListener` to make sure when `useEffect` call again, the old event will be removed.

Comment: thanks, can you explain that? I'm new in react hook :(

Comment: thanks again, I just try it, but when `setMyState(true)` in handle, code inside `useEffect` will run again. I just want it run first once when `props.run` is trigger :(